# Convert a string with into a data frame with different number of elements

Tags: r, string, datatable

I have a string which I need to convert into a data-frame. Some elements of the data-frame have two numbers separated by a hyphen, and in some instances just the hyphen. This is causing my read.table not to work.

```
df <-  read.table(text = string, col.names = c.names)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Example of data:

```
c.names <- c("Gap", "Fr", "Pairs", "Mdk")
string <- c("1 0.00020 1 - 25 2.54124\r\n 2 0.00029 2 - 26 2.54125\r\n 3 0.00020 3 - 27 2.54116\r\n 26 -0.00008 - -\r\n 27 -0.00007 - -\r\n 28 -0.00009 - -\r\n"
```

The output I am aiming for is:

```
Gap  Fr       Pairs     Mdk
1    0.00020   1 - 25   2.54124
2    0.00029   2 - 26   2.54125
3    0.00020   3 - 27   2.54116
26  -0.00008   -        -
27  -0.00007   -        -
28  -0.00009   -        -
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution using `data.table`

**sample data**

```
c.names <- c("Gap", "Fr", "Pairs", "Mdk")
string <- c("1 0.00020 1 - 25 2.54124\r\n 2 0.00029 2 - 26 2.54125\r\n 3 0.00020 3 - 27 2.54116\r\n 26 -0.00008 - -\r\n 27 -0.00007 - -\r\n 28 -0.00009 - -\r\n" )
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(string, fill = TRUE)
DT[, `:=`( V3 = ifelse( !is.na(V6), paste(V3, V4, V5), "-" ), 
           V4 = NULL, 
           V5 = NULL,
           V6 = ifelse( !is.na(V6), V6, "-" ))]
setnames(DT, names(DT), c.names)
```

**output**

```
DT

#    Gap       Fr  Pairs     Mdk
# 1:   1  0.00020 1 - 25 2.54124
# 2:   2  0.00029 2 - 26 2.54125
# 3:   3  0.00020 3 - 27 2.54116
# 4:  26 -0.00008      -       -
# 5:  27 -0.00007      -       -
# 6:  28 -0.00009      -       -
```

Comment: Thanks, that is spot on! I will have to study the second line DT[,':='  ...

Comment: That line looks if V6 (the sixth column of the data.table created by the fread-line before) is `NA`. If not, third column = paste the 3rd-4th-5th columns together, if NA, then third colum =  "-". Same goes for 6th column. 4th and 5th column can be dropped/deleted. Hint: look at the result (DT) from the line `DT <- fread(string, fill = TRUE)`. It will help you understand the operations I just described.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using base R.  Manually splits the string, since hyphen is not a valid delimiter (could be negative number) and space is not a consistent delimiter (since "pairs" column may have spaces when valid and none when not).

```
c.names <- c("Gap", "Fr", "Pairs", "Mdk")
string <- c("1 0.00020 1 - 25 2.54124\r\n 2 0.00029 2 - 26 2.54125\r\n 3 0.00020 3 - 27 2.54116\r\n 26 -0.00008 - -\r\n 27 -0.00007 - -\r\n 28 -0.00009 - -\r\n")

lines <- scan(text=string,what=character(),sep="\n")


df <- lapply(lines,function(line) {
  line <- trimws(line)
  breaks <- unlist(gregexpr("\\s+",line))
  gap <- trimws(substr(x=line,start=1,stop=breaks[1]))
  fr <- trimws(substr(x=line,start=breaks[1],stop=breaks[2]))
  pairs <- trimws(substr(x=line,start=breaks[2],stop=breaks[length(breaks)]))
  mdk <- trimws(substr(x=line,start=breaks[length(breaks)],stop=nchar(line)))
  data.frame(gap=gap,fr=fr,pairs=pairs,mdk=mdk)
})

df <- do.call("rbind",df)
> df
  gap       fr  pairs     mdk
1   1  0.00020 1 - 25 2.54124
2   2  0.00029 2 - 26 2.54125
3   3  0.00020 3 - 27 2.54116
4  26 -0.00008      -       -
5  27 -0.00007      -       -
6  28 -0.00009      -       -
```